# Show google maps on mobile website

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, google-maps

Is it possible to add google maps on a site designed specifically for the iPhone? I have never integrated maps in my websites before, so this question really goes more because of my inexperience. 
Using basic html and javascript at the moment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Google Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/) is specifically designed to work efficiently on mobile devices.  There are some great tutorials [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/introduction.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/articles.html).

Comment: Is it mandatory to have "API_KEY" ? I tried using "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" and it is working in desktop but not in mobile devices. Any alternatives please

Answer (score 6):

Any link to a Google Maps URL will automatically open in the Maps application, which may be more useful than simply embedding a map view in the website itself.

For example, a link to http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino will automatically open the Maps application and run a search for "cupertino".

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you only need a google map with some simple function. The simplest way is use the MapKit.Framework, it's a part of iphone OS. You can find the document [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/).

If you need to load your own web site, you need to use UIWebView. you can find the document here(http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I think these two ways can help you solve your problem.
And sorry about the link, because I'm not allowed to post more than one hyperlink.